# Menu retrátil quebra propriedades css quando acionado

Tags: jquery, css

```js
/*

Responsive Mobile Menu v1.0
Plugin URI: responsivemobilemenu.com

Author: Sergio Vitov
Author URI: http://xmacros.com

License: CC BY 3.0 http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/

*/

function responsiveMobileMenu() { 
  $('.rmm').each(function() {
   
   
   
   $(this).children('ul').addClass('rmm-main-list'); // mark main menu list
   
   
   var $style = $(this).attr('data-menu-style'); // get menu style
    if ( typeof $style == 'undefined' ||  $style == false )
     {
      $(this).addClass('graphite'); // set graphite style if style is not defined
     }
    else {
      $(this).addClass($style);
     }
     
     
   /*  width of menu list (non-toggled) */
   
   var $width = 0;
    $(this).find('ul li').each(function() {
     $width += $(this).outerWidth();
    });
    
   // if modern browser
   
   if ($.support.leadingWhitespace) {
    $(this).css('max-width' , $width*1.05+'px');
   }
   // 
   else {
    $(this).css('width' , $width*1.05+'px');
   }
  
   });
}
function getMobileMenu() {

 /*  build toggled dropdown menu list */
 
 $('.rmm').each(function() { 
    var menutitle = $(this).attr("data-menu-title");
    if ( menutitle == "" ) {
     menutitle = "Menu";
    }
    else if ( menutitle == undefined ) {
     menutitle = "Menu";
    }
    var $menulist = $(this).children('.rmm-main-list').html();
    var $menucontrols ="<div class='rmm-toggled-controls'><div class='rmm-toggled-title'>" + menutitle + "</div><div class='rmm-button'><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span></div></div>";
    $(this).prepend("<div class='rmm-toggled rmm-closed'>"+$menucontrols+"<ul>"+$menulist+"</ul></div>");

  });
}

function adaptMenu() {
 
 /*  toggle menu on resize */
 
 $('.rmm').each(function() {
   var $width = $(this).css('max-width');
   $width = $width.replace('px', ''); 
   if ( $(this).parent().width() < $width*1.05 ) {
    $(this).children('.rmm-main-list').hide(0);
    $(this).children('.rmm-toggled').show(0);
   }
   else {
    $(this).children('.rmm-main-list').show(0);
    $(this).children('.rmm-toggled').hide(0);
   }
  });
  
}

$(function() {

  responsiveMobileMenu();
  getMobileMenu();
  adaptMenu();
  
  /* slide down mobile menu on click */
  
  $('.rmm-toggled, .rmm-toggled .rmm-button').click(function(){
   if ( $(this).is(".rmm-closed")) {
     $(this).find('ul').stop().show(300);
     $(this).removeClass("rmm-closed");
   }
   else {
    $(this).find('ul').stop().hide(300);
     $(this).addClass("rmm-closed");
   }
  
 }); 

});
 /*  hide mobile menu on resize */
$(window).resize(function() {
  adaptMenu();
});
```

```css
/*

Responsive Mobile Menu v1.0
Plugin URI: responsivemobilemenu.com

Author: Sergio Vitov
Author URI: http://xmacros.com

License: CC BY 3.0 http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/

*/

.rmm {
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 padding:0px;
 margin:0 auto !important;
 text-align: center;
 line-height:19px !important;
}
.rmm * {
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent !important;
 font-family:Arial;
}
.rmm a {
 color:#ebebeb;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.rmm .rmm-main-list, .rmm .rmm-main-list li {
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}
.rmm ul {
 display:block;
 width:auto !important;
 margin:0 auto !important;
 overflow:hidden;
 list-style:none;
}


/* sublevel menu - in construction */
.rmm ul li ul, .rmm ul li ul li, .rmm ul li ul li a {
 display:none !important;
 height:0px !important;
 width:0px !important;
}
/* */


.rmm .rmm-main-list li {
 display:inline;
 padding:padding:0px;
 margin:0px !important;
}
.rmm-toggled {
 display:none;
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
 overflow:hidden;
 margin:0 auto !important;
}
.rmm-button:hover {
 cursor:pointer;
}
.rmm .rmm-toggled ul {
 display:none;
 margin:0px !important;
 padding:0px !important;
}
.rmm .rmm-toggled ul li {
 display:block;
 margin:0 auto !important;
}




/* GRAPHITE STYLE */

.rmm.graphite .rmm-main-list li a {
 display:inline-block;
 padding:8px 30px 8px 30px;
 margin:0px -3px 0px -3px;
 font-size:15px;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #333333;
 background-color:#444444;
 border-left:1px solid #555555;
 background-image:url('../rmm-img/graphite-menu-bg.png');
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-main-list li a:hover {
 background-image:url('../rmm-img/graphite-menu-bg-hover.png');
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-main-list li:first-child a {
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 6px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 6px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
border-top-left-radius: 6px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-main-list li:last-child a {
 -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 6px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
border-top-right-radius: 6px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled {
 width:95%;
 background-color:#555555;
 min-height:36px;
 border-radius:6px;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled-controls {
 display:block;
 height:36px;
 color:white;
 text-align:left;
 position:relative;
 background-image:url('../rmm-img/graphite-menu-bg.png');
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
 border-radius:6px;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled-title {
 position:relative;
 top:9px;
 left:15px;
 font-size:16px;
 color:white;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 1px black;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-button {
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 right:15px;
 top:8px;
}

.rmm.graphite .rmm-button span {
 display:block;
 margin-top:4px;
 height:2px;
 background:white;
 width:24px;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled ul li a {
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 background-color:#555555;
 text-align:center;
 padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;
 border-bottom:1px solid #333333;
 border-top:1px solid #777777;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #333333;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled ul li a:active {
 background-color:#444444;
 border-bottom:1px solid #444444;
 border-top:1px solid #444444;
}



/* SAPPHIRE STYLE */

.rmm.sapphire .rmm-main-list li a {
 display:inline-block;
 padding:8px 30px 8px 30px;
 margin:0px -3px 0px -3px;
 font-size:15px;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #3e587b;
 background-color:#537b9f;
 border-left:1px solid #3e587b;
 background-image:url('../rmm-img/sapphire-menu-bg.png');
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
.rmm.sapphire .rmm-main-list li a:hover {
 background:#3e597b;
}
.rmm.sapphire .rmm-main-list li:first-child a {
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
.rmm.sapphire .rmm-main-list li:last-child a {
 -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
.rmm.sapphire .rmm-toggled {
 width:95%;
 background-color:#537b9f;
 min-height:36px;
 border-radius:6px;
}
.rmm.sapphire .rmm-toggled-controls {
 display:block;
 height:36px;
 color:white;
 text-align:left;
 position:relative;
 background-image:url('../rmm-img/sapphire-menu-bg.png');
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
 border-radius:5px;
}
.rmm.sapphire .rmm-toggled-title {
 position:relative;
 top:9px;
 left:15px;
 font-size:16px;
 color:white;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #3e587b;
}
.rmm.sapphire .rmm-button {
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 right:9px;
 top:7px;
 width:20px;
 padding:0px 7px 0px 7px;
 border:1px solid #3e587b;
 border-radius:3px;
 background-image:url('../rmm-img/sapphire-menu-bg.png');
 background-position:top;
}

.rmm.sapphire .rmm-button span {
 display:block;
 margin:4px 0px 4px 0px;
 height:2px;
 background:white;
 width:20px;
}
.rmm.sapphire .rmm-toggled ul li a {
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 background-color:#537698;
 text-align:center;
 padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;
 border-bottom:1px solid #3c5779;
 border-top:1px solid #6883a6;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #333333;
}
.rmm.sapphire .rmm-toggled ul li a:active {
 background-color:#3c5779;
 border-bottom:1px solid #3c5779;
 border-top:1px solid #3c5779;
}
.rmm.sapphire .rmm-toggled ul li:first-child a { 
 border-top:1px solid #3c5779 !important;
}





/* MINIMAL STYLE */

.rmm.minimal a {
 color:#333333;
}
.rmm.minimal a:hover {
 opacity:0.7;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-main-list li a {
 display:inline-block;
 padding:8px 30px 8px 30px;
 margin:0px -3px 0px -3px;
 font-size:15px;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-toggled {
 width:95%;
 min-height:36px;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-toggled-controls {
 display:block;
 height:36px;
 color:#333333;
 text-align:left;
 position:relative;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-toggled-title {
 position:relative;
 top:9px;
 left:9px;
 font-size:16px;
 color:#33333;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-button {
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 right:9px;
 top:7px;
}

.rmm.minimal .rmm-button span {
 display:block;
 margin:4px 0px 4px 0px;
 height:2px;
 background:#333333;
 width:25px;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-toggled ul li a {
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;
 border-bottom:1px solid #dedede;
 color:#333333;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-toggled ul li:first-child a {
 border-top:1px solid #dedede;
}
@media (width: 20em){
.logo{
 max-width: 80%;
 margin: 1%;
 margin-left: 5%;
 float: left;
}
.logo img{
 max-width: 100%;
}
.social{
 max-width: 11%;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 2%;
}
.social img{
 max-width: 100%;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Responsive Mobile Menu</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="rmm-css/responsivemobilemenu.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="rmm-css/estilizacao_reader.css" type="text/css"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="rmm-js/responsivemobilemenu.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <header>
  <div class="logo">
   <img src="img/logo.png"/>
  </div>
  <div class="social">
   <img src="img/facebook2.gif"/>
   <img src="img/twitter2.gif"/>
   <img src="img/isntagran2.gif"/>
  </div>
 </header>

        <div class="rmm">
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#home'>Home</a></li>
                <li><a href='#about-me'>About me</a></li>
                <li><a href='#gallery'>Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href='#blog'>Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href='#links'>Links</a></li>
                <li><a href='#sitemap'>Sitemap</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Estou criando um site para melhorar minhas habilidades com html e CSS.
Estou tentando entender melhor sobre os menus retráteis e estou com um problema que já ocorreram com dois menus que baixei para utilizar de exemplo.

Eu tenho o menu pronto, apenas alterei as informações dentro do `li` e comecei a inserir o logotipo, link para redes sociais, essas coisas.

Enquanto eu não clico em nada no menu, o *layout* se mantém da maneira que eu quero. O problema é quando eu clico no menu para que ele me mostre as opções, ele perde todas as informações do css que eu coloquei nas outras `div`.

Acredito que tenha algo no Javascript (que não entendo nada) que faz isso, porque não consigo identificar nada no html e CSS.

Código Javascript:

```
function responsiveMobileMenu() {
    $('.rmm').each(function () {

        $(this).children('ul').addClass('rmm-main-list'); // mark main menu list

        var $style = $(this).attr('data-menu-style'); // get menu style
        if (typeof $style == 'undefined' || $style == false){
            $(this).addClass('graphite'); // set graphite style if style is not defined
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass($style);
        }

        /* width of menu list (non-toggled) */
        var $width = 0;
        $(this).find('ul li').each(function () {
            $width += $(this).outerWidth();
        });

        // if modern browser
        if ($.support.leadingWhitespace) {
            $(this).css('max-width', $width * 1.05 + 'px');
        }
        else {
            $(this).css('width', $width * 1.05 + 'px');
        }

    });
}
function getMobileMenu() {

    /*  build toggled dropdown menu list */
    $('.rmm').each(function () {
        var menutitle = $(this).attr("data-menu-title");
        if (menutitle == "") {
            menutitle = "Menu";
        }
        else if (menutitle == undefined) {
            menutitle = "Menu";
        }
        var $menulist = $(this).children('.rmm-main-list').html();
        var $menucontrols = "<div class='rmm-toggled-controls'><div class='rmm-toggled-title'>" + menutitle + "</div><div class='rmm-button'><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span></div></div>";
        $(this).prepend("<div class='rmm-toggled rmm-closed'>" + $menucontrols + "<ul>" + $menulist + "</ul></div>");

    });
}

function adaptMenu() {

    /*  toggle menu on resize */
    $('.rmm').each(function () {
        var $width = $(this).css('max-width');
        $width = $width.replace('px', '');
        if ($(this).parent().width() < $width * 1.05) {
            $(this).children('.rmm-main-list').hide(0);
            $(this).children('.rmm-toggled').show(0);
        }
        else {
            $(this).children('.rmm-main-list').show(0);
            $(this).children('.rmm-toggled').hide(0);
        }
    });

}

$(function () {
    responsiveMobileMenu();
    getMobileMenu();
    adaptMenu();

    /* slide down mobile menu on click */
    $('.rmm-toggled, .rmm-toggled .rmm-button').click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(".rmm-closed")) {
            $(this).find('ul').stop().show(300);
            $(this).removeClass("rmm-closed");
        }
        else {
            $(this).find('ul').stop().hide(300);
            $(this).addClass("rmm-closed");
        }

    });
});

/*  hide mobile menu on resize */
$(window).resize(function () {
    adaptMenu();
});
```

CSS

```
/*

Responsive Mobile Menu v1.0
Plugin URI: responsivemobilemenu.com

Author: Sergio Vitov
Author URI: http://xmacros.com

License: CC BY 3.0 http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/

*/

.rmm {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0 auto !important;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:19px !important;
}
.rmm * {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent !important;
    font-family:Arial;
}
.rmm a {
    color:#ebebeb;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.rmm .rmm-main-list, .rmm .rmm-main-list li {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.rmm ul {
    display:block;
    width:auto !important;
    margin:0 auto !important;
    overflow:hidden;
    list-style:none;
}


/* sublevel menu - in construction */
.rmm ul li ul, .rmm ul li ul li, .rmm ul li ul li a {
    display:none !important;
    height:0px !important;
    width:0px !important;
}
/* */


.rmm .rmm-main-list li {
    display:inline;
    padding:padding:0px;
    margin:0px !important;
}
.rmm-toggled {
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0 auto !important;
}
.rmm-button:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}
.rmm .rmm-toggled ul {
    display:none;
    margin:0px !important;
    padding:0px !important;
}
.rmm .rmm-toggled ul li {
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto !important;
}




/* GRAPHITE STYLE */

.rmm.graphite .rmm-main-list li a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:8px 30px 8px 30px;
    margin:0px -3px 0px -3px;
    font-size:15px;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #333333;
    background-color:#444444;
    border-left:1px solid #555555;
    background-image:url('../rmm-img/graphite-menu-bg.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-main-list li a:hover {
    background-image:url('../rmm-img/graphite-menu-bg-hover.png');
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-main-list li:first-child a {
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 6px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 6px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
border-top-left-radius: 6px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-main-list li:last-child a {
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 6px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
border-top-right-radius: 6px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled {
    width:95%;
    background-color:#555555;
    min-height:36px;
    border-radius:6px;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled-controls {
    display:block;
    height:36px;
    color:white;
    text-align:left;
    position:relative;
    background-image:url('../rmm-img/graphite-menu-bg.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    border-radius:6px;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled-title {
    position:relative;
    top:9px;
    left:15px;
    font-size:16px;
    color:white;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px black;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-button {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    right:15px;
    top:8px;
}

.rmm.graphite .rmm-button span {
    display:block;
    margin-top:4px;
    height:2px;
    background:white;
    width:24px;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled ul li a {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#555555;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #333333;
    border-top:1px solid #777777;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #333333;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled ul li a:active {
    background-color:#444444;
    border-bottom:1px solid #444444;
    border-top:1px solid #444444;
}



/* SAPPHIRE STYLE */

.rmm.sapphire .rmm-main-list li a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:8px 30px 8px 30px;
    margin:0px -3px 0px -3px;
    font-size:15px;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #3e587b;
    background-color:#537b9f;
    border-left:1px solid #3e587b;
    background-image:url('../rmm-img/sapphire-menu-bg.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
.rmm.sapphire .rmm-main-list li a:hover {
    background:#3e597b;
}
.rmm.sapphire .rmm-main-list li:first-child a {
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
.rmm.sapphire .rmm-main-list li:last-child a {
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
.rmm.sapphire .rmm-toggled {
    width:95%;
    background-color:#537b9f;
    min-height:36px;
    border-radius:6px;
}
.rmm.sapphire .rmm-toggled-controls {
    display:block;
    height:36px;
    color:white;
    text-align:left;
    position:relative;
    background-image:url('../rmm-img/sapphire-menu-bg.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.rmm.sapphire .rmm-toggled-title {
    position:relative;
    top:9px;
    left:15px;
    font-size:16px;
    color:white;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #3e587b;
}
.rmm.sapphire .rmm-button {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    right:9px;
    top:7px;
    width:20px;
    padding:0px 7px 0px 7px;
    border:1px solid #3e587b;
    border-radius:3px;
    background-image:url('../rmm-img/sapphire-menu-bg.png');
    background-position:top;
}

.rmm.sapphire .rmm-button span {
    display:block;
    margin:4px 0px 4px 0px;
    height:2px;
    background:white;
    width:20px;
}
.rmm.sapphire .rmm-toggled ul li a {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#537698;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #3c5779;
    border-top:1px solid #6883a6;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #333333;
}
.rmm.sapphire .rmm-toggled ul li a:active {
    background-color:#3c5779;
    border-bottom:1px solid #3c5779;
    border-top:1px solid #3c5779;
}
.rmm.sapphire .rmm-toggled ul li:first-child a { 
    border-top:1px solid #3c5779 !important;
}





/* MINIMAL STYLE */

.rmm.minimal a {
    color:#333333;
}
.rmm.minimal a:hover {
    opacity:0.7;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-main-list li a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:8px 30px 8px 30px;
    margin:0px -3px 0px -3px;
    font-size:15px;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-toggled {
    width:95%;
    min-height:36px;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-toggled-controls {
    display:block;
    height:36px;
    color:#333333;
    text-align:left;
    position:relative;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-toggled-title {
    position:relative;
    top:9px;
    left:9px;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#33333;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-button {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    right:9px;
    top:7px;
}

.rmm.minimal .rmm-button span {
    display:block;
    margin:4px 0px 4px 0px;
    height:2px;
    background:#333333;
    width:25px;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-toggled ul li a {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #dedede;
    color:#333333;
}
.rmm.minimal .rmm-toggled ul li:first-child a {
    border-top:1px solid #dedede;
}
```

Comment: Vai por mim, ninguém vai baixar um arquivo zip para procurar o problema, sem contar que provavelmente depois você irá excluir esse arquivo e a pergunta [não será útil para outros usuários](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Reproduza o menu em algum site que permita vê-lo online, como o [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ou [*criando um snippet*](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2115/apresentando-js-css-e-html-execut%c3%a1veis) aqui mesmo no StackOverflow.

Comment: Eu tentei colocar lá os códigos e não consegui porque esse menu que tenho utiliza imagens e o snippet não suporta, além de não saber qual é a parte importante do código que eles pedem para ser exibida porque, como disse, estou iniciando :/ vou ver se consigo colocar e já mando uma resposta.

Comment: Olha ai. Não coloquei o html pq ele é simples, não tem nada de mais

Comment: Matheus, imagens, ícones, etc não tem muita importância, pode ficar tranquilo. O importante é postar um exemplo que mostre o funcionamento do código para tentarmos entender o que você pretende fazer e te ajudar, ele não precisa estar bonito mas precisa funcionar. Pelo menos eu não entendi o que quis dizer com "*O problema é quando eu clico no menu para que ele me mostre as opções, ele perde todas as informações do css que eu coloquei nas outras divs*"...

Comment: Agora que editei a pergunta, vi que as funções possuem dependência do [jQuery](https://jquery.com) para funcionar. Você está importando o jQuery antes desse código javascript que postou na pergunta?

Comment: Consegui colocar o snippet. Acho que pode ficar mais fácil assim. Se puder, coloque algumas imagens ai para rodar no seu computador o código. O que acontece, é que se eu clico em cima do menu para ele abrir(tendo redimensionado o navegador para que o menu fique visitável em um display mobile) ele perde as propriedades css das imagens.

Comment: re22, encontrei o problema!! na hora que eu chamo a media querie eu não estava declarando como min-width. Ajustando isso funcionou corretamente. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!